# change of basis calculation step 2

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

I'm practicing using this [textbook](https://www.math.purdue.edu/files/academic/courses/2010spring/MA26200/4-7.pdf#:%7E:text=Find%20the%20change-of-basis%20matrix%20fromB%20toC%2C%20and%20use,quick%20calculation%2C%20we%20%EF%AC%81nd%20thata1%3D%200.5%2Ca2%3D%E2%88%920.5%2C%20anda3%3D%200.)
I have the following $V=R^2 B = {(1,2),(3,4)}, C = {(7,3),(4,2)}$ and $v = (1,0)$...
The solution shows

a) determine $[v]B$ and $[V]C$

b) find $P C\leftarrow B$
.....

I'm getting stuck on b)

For step a) we obtain $[v]B = [-1,1], [V]C = [1,-1.5]$. I get this!

Then step b) it shows:
$[(1,2)]C = [-3, 5.5]$ and $[(3,4)]C = [-5,9.5]$
I'm stuck on what C is and how they obtain the values....

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand how b) is calculated.

We want to find $[B_1]_C, [B_2]_C$, aka what are the component vectors of B over C?

$B_1 = (1,2),$ and $C = (7,3), (4,2)$:

$c_1 (7,3) + c_2(4,2) = (1,2)$

$c_1 = -3$...
and we continue from there